# Cumulative sum of items in a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
X = [{"t":1, "a":1, "b":3},
     {"t":2, "a":2, "b":4}]
```

How do I get:

```
[{"t":1, "a":1, "b":3}, {"t":2, "a":3, "b":7}]
```

In the second element of the desired output, the value for `"b"` is `7`, which is the cumulative sum of `"b"` values up to that point, and likewise for other keys.

I know I can do this via pandas.  But is there a more pythonic solution?

Comment: Can you [edit] so it's actually valid syntax and explain the output and how you'd do this in pandas? (Neither your input/output is actually valid)

Comment: `pandas` is a python package. Show us your implementation

Comment: And what about the values for the `"t"` keys?

Comment: Did you mean: `{"t": 3, "a": 3,"b": 7}`?

Comment: I m not sure why I got voted down.  the "t" here shouldnl't be accumulated.  its time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the fact that `collections.Counter` objects update in the way you want to accumulate:

```
import collections


def cumulative_elementwise_sum(ds):
    result = collections.Counter()
    for d in ds:
        result.update(d)
        yield dict(result)
```

This will also "do the right thing" when a new key is encountered.  Example:

```
>>> x = [
...    {'t': 1, 'a': 1, 'b': 3},
...    {'t': 2, 'a': 2, 'b': 4},
...    {'t': 1, 'a': 4, 'b': 1, 'd': 2},
... ]
>>> list(cumulative_elementwise_sum(x))
[{'t': 1, 'a': 1, 'b': 3},
 {'t': 3, 'a': 3, 'b': 7},
 {'t': 4, 'a': 7, 'b': 8, 'd': 2}]
```

If you're using Python 3.8, the [`iteratools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) method has gained an `initial` argument, so this can be simplified to:

```
def updated(c, items):
    c.update(items)
    return c

map(dict, itertools.accumulate(x, updated, initial=collections.Counter()))
```

If you only need the final result, and not the whole sequence of intermediate results, that can be obtained using `functools.reduce`, of course:

```
import functools

>>> functools.reduce(updated, x, collections.Counter())
Counter({'t': 4, 'a': 7, 'b': 8, 'd': 2})

# dict version
>>> dict(functools.reduce(updated, x, collections.Counter()))
{'t': 4, 'a': 7, 'b': 8, 'd': 2}
```

Comment: This can be made more concise by using the lambda function: `lambda u, v: u + collections.Counter(v)` instead of defining `updated`. Then, we can write, for example, the one-liner: `dict(functools.reduce(lambda u, v: u + collections.Counter(v), x, collections.Counter()))`.